# using 'this' keyword with extended classes in java

Tags: java, class, this, extends

I have a class called 'Items' to which 'Equips' extends from and 'Helmet' then extends from 'Equips'. I have a method called 'getStats' that loads the item's stats from a .txt file. If I put the 'getStats' method in the 'Items' class, whatever field I try to access in a 'Helmet' object using 'this.' shows up null. The field I'm trying to access in 'Helmet' is initialized when the helmet is created before the text file is loaded. I could very easily just put the 'getStats' method in the 'Equips' class and put a blank 'getStats' method in the 'Items' class, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it work how it is. Thanks in advance!

**Items.java:**

```
package com.projects.aoa;

import static com.projects.aoa.Print.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Items {

String name, type;
int id;
int hp, mp, str, def;
boolean vacent;

static void getAllStats(Items[] e){
    for(Items i : e){
        getItemStats(i);
    }
}

static void getItemStats(Items i){
    i.getStats();
}

void getStats(){
    try {
        //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        print(this.name); //THIS shows up as null as well as those \/below\/
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") 
                + "/src/com/projects/aoa/" + this.type + this.name + ".txt");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        int counter = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.length() == 0){
                break;
            }

            switch (counter) {
            case 0:
                this.hp = Integer.parseInt(line);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.mp = Integer.parseInt(line);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.def = Integer.parseInt(line);
                counter++;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.str = Integer.parseInt(line);
                counter++;
                break;
            }   
        }


        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

**Game.java:**

```
Helmet headBand = new Helmet("HeadBand");
Helmet bronzeHelmet = new Helmet("BronzeHelmet");


    Items[] equips = {
            headBand, bronzeHelmet
    };



    getAllStats(equips);
```

**Equips.java:**

```
  package com.projects.aoa;

import static com.projects.aoa.Print.print;
import static com.projects.aoa.Print.println;

import java.io.*;



class Equips extends Items{
    String name, type;
    int hp, mp, str, def;




    void printStats(){
        println("[" + name + "]");
        println("Type: " + type);
        println("HP:  " + hp);
        println("MP:  " + mp);
        println("Def: " + def);
        println("Str: " + str);
    }
}

class Helmet extends Equips {
    Helmet(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = "h_";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code from `Helmet` as well? I suspect that the `Helmet` class also has a `name` parameter, or else you are just forgetting to set the `name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown us your `Helmet` class, so it's hard to say what's going on - but my *guess* is that you're redeclaring fields with the same name in `Helmet`. Those will *hide* the fields in `Items`, whereas you really just want to use the fields from `Items`.

So here's a short but complete example which demonstrates what I *think* is going on:

```
class SuperClass {
    String name;

    public void setName(String newName) {
        // This writes to the field in SuperClass
        name = newName;
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    // This *hides* the field in SuperClass
    String name;

    public void showName() {
        // This reads the field from SubClass, which
        // nothing writes to...
        System.out.println("My name is " + name);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass x = new SubClass();
        x.setName("Test");
        x.showName();
    }
}
```

I would recommend that:

- You make all fields private, writing properties to give access to other classes as required
- You get rid of the fields in `Helmet` which hide the ones in `Items`
- You change your class names to avoid the plurality - `Item` and `Equipment` instead of `Items`

Here's a fixed version of the above code:

```
class SuperClass {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void showName() {
        System.out.println("My name is " + getName());
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass x = new SubClass();
        x.setName("Test");
        x.showName();
    }
}
```

(Obviously you also need to think about what access to put on the properties etc, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Ohhh yeah that was it. Items was originally an interface so I had to declare those again in Equips. I'm new to java :/ Thanks for you your help!